# popup form centered on desktop but not on mobil

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have a page where when you click on a link and you are not logged in a form pops up to login. It works perfect on desktop and is always centered on the page but on mobil it is at the top so if I click on a link towards the bottom of the page I have to scroll all the way up to see it. My css for the form is:

```
div.wpcf7 {
position: absolute;
margin: 0 auto;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
width: 490px;
height: 440px; 
z-index: 1042;
background: #f9f9f9;
}
```

Comment: Did you try using `position: fixed;` ?

Comment: that did the trick, don't know why I didn't think of that :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolute is with respect to page. Fixed is with respect to window(the viewport).

```
 position: fixed;
```